# What does Rashi mean by לין שם דבר?

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, rashi, parashat-chaye-sara

[Rashi on bereshis 24:23](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219#v=23&showrashi=true) says "לין שם דבר." ie. "lin" is a noun. How does that fit in the context considering that Eliezer was asking for a place to "lodge". Even though lodge can be a noun, in this context it would seem a verb.

Comment: Welcome again, and I hope to see you around! Thanks for the question :-)

Comment: So your question is that _Rashi_'s explanation doesn't seem to fit in with the English translation?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_38046_34.pdf

Comment: Yishai, if I am understanding your link to Dikdukei Rashi correctly, not all agree with Rashi. Nonetheless how do we explain Rashi's view? Especially with the prefix ל - "to" lin?

Comment: Shmuel -- tip for you: if you want to make sure that someone sees your response to their comments, write their username, preceded by the `@` symbol....I'm not sure that @Yishai saw your response.

Comment: @ShmuelNavi, I think what is confusing you is that you translate the ל as "to" unambiguously. "To" is an appropriate translation when it precedes a verb. When it precedes a noun, it would be "for". For example, לדירה.

Comment: @Yishai, Are you saying the same thing Shalom is in his answer?

Comment: @ShmuelNavi, I'm not sure about everything in his answer but the use of the word "for" in the translation is the point. Once you read it that way, I think your question is mostly satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He asked: "is there a place for a *spend-the-night*." *Lin* is a noun. It means "one night's lodgings."

She replied: "there is a place to lodge." *Lun* is a verb, "to lodge."

Comment: Thank you. If so, shouldn't "mokom lanu lolin" be all the same noun? Is that what you mean? If so why does Rashi say that only "lin" is a noun?

Comment: @ShmuelNavi, "makom" is clearly a noun. The point is that "lin" is a noun. "A place for A NIGHT'S SLEEP." Compare: "do we have a place in our house for A PIANO?" [noun], vs. "do we have a place in our house for PLAYING MUSIC?" [verb -- well, gerund, but close enough].